# Handling a windows-1250 URI in node.js/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, encoding, iconv

My app depends on a webservice to form it's URIs, so sometimes it comes up with (what I believe is) a windows-1250 encoded string (`/punk%92d`) and express fails as follows:

> Connect
>   400 Error: Failed to decode param 'punk%92d'
>   at Layer.match

So I thought about converting each link to that segment into utf-8 (example: `/punk’d`, so there would be no reference to the offending enconding), and back again to windows-1250 to work with the external webservice.

I tried this approach using both `iconv` and `iconv-lite` but there's always something wrong with the results: `/punk d`, `/punk�d`, etc.

Here's a sample using iconv:

```
var str = 'punk’d';
var buf = new Buffer(str.toString('binary'), 'binary');
console.log(new Iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1250').convert(buf).toString('binary'));
```

…and iconv-lite:

```
console.log(iconv.decode(new Buffer(str), 'win1250'));
```

I know using `binary` is a bad approach, but I was hoping something, *anything* would just do the job. I obviously tried multiple variations of this code since my knowledge of `Buffers` is limited, an even simpler things wouldn't work, like:

```
console.log(new Buffer('punk’d').toString('utf-8'));
```

So I'm interested in either a way to handle those encoded strings in the URI within express, or an effective way to convert them within node.js.

Comment: So, do I understand this correctly that you're building the URIs by which someone will access your app based on the data returned from a web service? Is there some reason that the problem characters *must* be maintained, because it seems as though your users might have just as much trouble *sending* you those characters as you have *receiving* them. If it were me, I'd find a way to remove or replace them and just use ASCII URIs.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this seems like too simple of a thing to try, but since Node and Express are both JavaScript, have you tried simply using `decodeURIComponent('punk’d')`? It looks to me that it's simply a standard encoded URI. I think you're getting that weird output from iconv because you're converting from the wrong encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sometimes we overlook things like that. In this case though I get `punk�d` by using `decodeURIComponent` alone. Am I missing something else?

Comment: You're getting the question mark character because there isn't a matching character in the character set to display it. The data should still be correct to actually load the URL though. URLs aren't transmitted in UTF-8 format.

Comment: If decodeURIComponent is used to convert it to `punk�d`, then it will be encoded back to its original value when it passes through encodeURIComponent.

Comment: Yeeahh… no :D I tried that already. First of all, the "decoded" string `punk�d` wouldn't load the data correctly, the target web service didn't recognize the name. Then, if I encode it back, I get another garbled string. I didn't copy it but it was something like `punkfsd`, not the original value. But I'm open to try any other suggestions you got (:

Comment: Here's another odd idea, but have you tried escaping the URL? escape()